# Given a millions of points, finds points that lie on the line or in the range of 0.2 mm distance from the line

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, math

<strike>Given a set of millions of points with (x,y) co-ordinates, I have to selects points which are  on the line[(x1,y1)-(x2,y2)] or are in the range(distance) of 0.2 mm from the line.</strike>

One way to solve this 
1) put every point in the equation of line, if it satisfies then point lies on the line
2) calculate perpendicular distance between point and line , if distance is less than 0.2 mm then select this point

but for millions of point it will not be best solution, so i am looking for new algorithm or techniques with which we can solve above problem.

Any help will be highly appreciated! thank you.

Thanks for your reply, I have gone through all the suggestions posted by you. I think, I would have given you a some background of the problem.

I am new to c++ programming and description of the problem that i am facing is as follow

1. input to the program is a comma separated text file that contains millions or billions of  x & y co-ordinates with some value at each point
   e.g. x1, y1, value1
2. then program draws thousands of lines ([x1,y1]-[x2,y2])
3. and for the each line i have to select a set of points that lie on the line or are in the range of 0 to 0.2 mm

I tried following methods:

1. calculated distance of the each points from the line , if distance <= 0.2 then select such point, and did it for thousands of line...but it is not  efficient algorithm
2. in second method i plan to sort co-ordinates, and then i draw parallel lines on both side of given line at a distance of 0.2 mm.... but don't know how to identify the points that lie between the parallel lines. also suggest if this method is good

some of you suggested to use r trees, 2-variant method, since i am new to programming pl suggest some online tutorial to understand & how to implement the same

Comment: Are you really comparing with *one* line? If you'll be assessing the same set of points for multiple lines, it may be worth building some kind of index of the points. There's a few spacial data structures that might work for the points - the real trick would be implementing an efficient search. If you really are searching for one line, you can't avoid doing some work for every single point. Think of searching a sorted array for a value as an analogy - it's fine once you *have* a sorted array, but you wouldn't sort an array just to do one search because sorting costs more than the search.

Comment: Variant 2 is the best solution, since each point is examined only once.Variant 1 is excessive - equation is satisfied when and only when the distance is 0.

Answer (score 6):

To compare all the points pretty much all you can do is compare all the points.

You can split the task over multiple threads to get it processed faster but I think you are underestimating the speed of computers.

Do the simple implementation first and see if it is fast enough before trying to complicate things.

Comment: +1 for `underestimating the speed of computers`

Answer (score 3):

How about rotating the plane so the line becomes an axis, say the x-axis?  You don't need to apply the entire rotation matrix to every point either.  You just need to check the y-coordinate of the rotated point, and in fact, you probably don't need to do the whole computation most of the time either, since you can do some simple tests to see if you'll be within the needed distance from the x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

[R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) sounds like what you need.
This data structure allows you to query your data base for what point lies within the given box (in your case a line with width 0.2).

So the change you will need is the rotation of you points, now I'm not sure the data structure will work if you just treat you point as rotated, but even then you problem became much simpler and it's to rotate your points, then construct the tree and query.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To estimate time needed to solve the problem above let consider the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
x1=1.1
x2=1.0
y1=8.0
y2=3.2
#preliminary computation to obtain canonical equation of the line (x1,y1)---(x2,y2)
d=(x2-x1)**(-2.0)+(y1-y2)**(-2)
g=lambda (x,y):1/(x2-x1)/np.sqrt(d)*x+y/(y1-y2)/np.sqrt(d)-(x1/(x2-x1)+y1/(y1-y2))/np.sqrt(d)
# Now: g((3,4)) computes the distance between the line and the point (3,4)
np.random.rand(10**6,2) #generate 1 mil. of points 
result=map(lambda x: np.abs(g(x))<=0.2, points) #computes all cases when distance from current point to the line is less 0.2
```

Computation time: approx. 15 sec, Athlon x4, 2Ghz, Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

you can also do some some preliminary filtering of all the points: consider the circle centered at ((x1+x2)/2, (y1+y2)/2 ) and R = length_of_the_line/2+offset (offset = 0.2mm).

If the point is inside the circle compute the perpendicular distance between point and line, if distance is less than 0.2 mm then select this point.
If the point is outside the circle don't select it

This should save you some cycles since it's easier to check if a point is inside a circle than to compute the perpendicular distance for every point.

Hope it helps.